# VBA 3 Dimensional Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have to use nested For/Next loops to populate a multi-dimensional array that holds the data from ranges A1:E5 on the previous 3 sheets. I then want to display the array on the current sheet. This is for class and the book really doesn't cover using 3 dimensional arrays much.

```
Private Sub multiWorksheetArray_Click()

Dim multiSheetArray(2, 4, 4) As Variant 'array with 3 sheets, 5 columns/rows
Dim I As Integer 'counters
Dim J As Integer
Dim S As Integer


For S = 1 To 3
    For I = 1 To 5
        For J = 1 To 5
           'populate the array
            multiArray(S - 1, J - 1, I - 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" + S).Cells(J, I).Value
        Next J
    Next I
Next S

Range("A15:O19").Value = multiArray

End Sub
```

Comment: A sheet is 2D. How are you going to put a 3D array on it?

Comment: Miscellaneous suggestions. (1) VBA allows you to set the lower bounds of an array. Replace `Dim multiSheetArray(2, 4, 4) As Variant` by `Dim multiSheetArray(1 To 3, 1 To 5, 1 To 5) As Variant` and `multiArray(S - 1, J - 1, I - 1)` can become `multiArray(S, J, I)` which is much clearer. (2) You declare array as `multiSheetArray` but access it as `multiArray`. (3) I agree with GSerg, in `Range.Value = MyArray`, `MyArray` cannot be 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup:** I set the value of each cell in Range("A1:E5") on the first 3 sheets to it's external address:

---

```
Sub Setup()
    Dim w As Long
    Dim c As Range

    For w = 1 To 3
        For Each c In Worksheets(i).[A1:E5]
            c = c.Address(External:=True)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Test:** Iterate over each element in the 3D Array and push it's and push the element's value into a range that is 3 cells wide.  Because `For Each Loops` iterate over its elements column by column and range's fill values row by row extending past the range's boundary,  the values will natural fill in.

---

```
Sub Test3DArray()
    Dim w As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim multiSheetArray(2, 4, 4) As Variant    'array with 3 sheets, 5 columns/rows

    For w = 1 To 3
        With Worksheets(w)
            For x = 1 To 5
                For y = 1 To 5
                    multiSheetArray(w - 1, x - 1, y - 1) = .Cells(x, y)
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next

    For Each v In multiSheetArray
        With Worksheets(4)
            z = z + 1
            .Range("A1:C1").Cells(z) = v
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: in the setup procedure you posted it seems to me the index variable i in worksheets should be a w the way you have your loop setup.  For Each c In Worksheets(w).[A1:E5]

Answer (score 2):

The practical way storing the data is to have a 1D array filled with 2D arrays.  This will allow you to use standard techniques to work with thee data.

```
Sub Test3DArray()
    Dim w As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim v(4, 4) As Variant
    Dim multiSheetArray(2) As Variant    'array with 3 sheets, 5 columns/rows

    multiSheetArray(0) = v
    multiSheetArray(1) = v

    For w = 1 To 2
        With Worksheets(w)
            For x = 1 To 5
                For y = 1 To 5
                    multiSheetArray(w - 1)(x - 1, y - 1) = .Cells(x, y)
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next

    multiSheetArray(2) = Worksheets(3).Range("A1:E5").Value

    With Worksheets(4)
        .Range("A1:E5").Value = multiSheetArray(0)

        .Range("A1:E5").Offset(6).Value = multiSheetArray(1)

        .Range("A1:E5").Offset(12).Value = multiSheetArray(2)
    End With

End Sub
```

### Results:

[image]